# Steam is not working correctly Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 1068, in <module> sys.exit(main())

Tags: apt, package-management, steam

I can`t update some steam packages because of this error. I use Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

```
The packages cache seems to be out of date

Press return to update the list of available packages: 
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 1068, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 899, in main
    package = create_package(section)
  File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 392, in create_package
    name = remap_package(name)
  File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 325, in remap_package
    cache = apt.Cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 214, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
apt_pkg.Error: E:Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list (URI), E:The list of sources could not be read.

Press return to continue:
```

When i press return, steam is opening but i can`t open games
I did not make any changes to the python3 default.
I just saw that I can't use `apt update` and `apt upgrade` too. When i try to use it, it shows me this :

```
borys@boryslinux:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for borys: 
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
borys@boryslinux:~$ sudo apt update
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
borys@boryslinux:~$
```

Comment: Sounds like this would be a good thing to lookup on the Steam support site. https://help.steampowered.com/en/

Comment: Given the python3 errors; have you made any changes to the python3 defaults?  (*your error shows a problem with your sources & likely change to python3 too*)

Comment: I have edited the question, please look

Comment: Yes, problems disappeared only after deleting it in gedit, trying to fix is wasn`t working